# PHP - big datalist option

Tags: php, mysql, datalist

I have function which show **70.000** `option` values in webpage, is there any option to do "autosuggestion"? Now there is the problem with performance, the browswere are crashed after 2 - 3 searches

```
while($row_ICAO = $airports_ICAO->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<option value='{$row_ICAO['ICAO']}'></option>";
}
```

Maybe there is another option to do this and browsers won't crash?

Comment: Here is example you can use for multiple option search... http://jsfiddle.net/jgf5fkfL/105/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**@Dayek**,

I will prefer this.
First don't fetch any data when form load.
when user click on select2 input provide search functionality,
when user start typing for search at that time you need to implement ajax call for fetch related data ( user type in select2 search input ) from database table.
Please refer this [**link**](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)

Comment: I solved this problem using "Autocomplete Search Box in PHP MySQL using jQuery UI and Ajax"

Comment: Happy to hear that, you solved issue. :)

Comment: @Dayek - You can self-answer the question and take the answer-points.  But be sure to give an overview of how that package works, plus a link to it.